# Rewriting History to Converge Two Orphaned Trees

Tags: git

I have a repository that looks like this:

[image]

These are two orphaned trees in the same repository.

Commit **B** was created by modifying commit **A** (but this was not recorded by git)

Changes from commit **C** were manually (file by file editing) merged into the left tree creating commit **D** (again, not recorded by git).

Now I want merge **E** and **F**.

How can I rewrite the history (or any other method) so that this merge ,and any subsequent merges between the trees, will be automatic?

Comment: Why not simply merge E and F? Do you really need to rewrite history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "grafts" to provisionally rewire ancestry, and `git filter-branch` to lock it in.  Here,

```
echo `git rev-parse $B $A` >> .git/info/grafts        # $B etc are shas or however
echo `git rev-parse $D $B $C` >> .git/info/grafts     # you want to refer to the commits
```

tell this particular repo to behave as if A was listed as B's first parent, and as if D had B and C for parents. Then you can do the merge, and git will find the correct merge base.  At this point just deleting the grafts file is an option since there might not be much point going back and rewriting the earlier commit ancestries, since you've got a correct merge base for any future work, but if rewrite is an option for you a `git filter-branch -- --all` will apply all the grafts you listed.

Do this in a scratch repo so you can experiment:

```
git clone -s . $TMPDIR/foo
cd !$
mkdir .git/info

# do the echoes above here, then
git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all
# will show you that this repo sees the grafted ancestry links.

git filter-branch -- --all
```

and it will pop messages showing you which references were moved to rewritten history and which weren't.

Back out procedure if anything goes wrong here is to cd back to your original repo and wipe the clone.  Anything goes right, force-push the rewrites back to your main repo (if a rewritten branch is checked out there you'll have to detach your HEAD from it first, `cd -; git checkout @^0; cd -; git push etc; cd -; git checkout @{-1}`).

Comment: The second `>` will overwrite the output from the first `>`

Comment: Thanks for introducing me grafts :)